# DJANGO relationship queries

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, relationship

I require assistance building a query for related fields. I need to show the each Product and its associated Product_Line item.  The relationship between the Product Line Item to the Product is one to many with the Product_Line item being unique to the Product.

I have included the following models, the relevant view and the html for the home as well as an output of the fields on the page.  Please help

**formulary/models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    #linkedProduct = models.ForeignKey(Product_Line, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    form = models.ForeignKey(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk) + " " + self.name + " " + str(self.form)

class Product_Line(models.Model):
    linked_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.ForeignKey(Active, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    strength = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    UoM = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['linked_product']
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)+ " "+ str(self.active) + " " + str(self.strength) + " " + str(self.UoM)
```

**inventory/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from list.models import Form

# Create your models here.

 
class Active(models.Model):
    long_descr =  models.CharField(max_length=10)
    drug_form = models.ForeignKey(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.long_descr

class Excipient(models.Model):
    long_descr =  models.CharField(max_length=10)
    drug_form = models.ForeignKey(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.long_descr
```

**formulary/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product_Line, Product, Active

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    product = Product.objects.all()
    productList = Product_Line.objects.all()
    active = Active.objects.all()
    context = {'product':product, 'productList': productList, 'active':active}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

**formulary/home.html**

```
<style>
   table {
       font-family:arial, sans-serif;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       width:100%;
   }
   td, th {
       border:1px solid #dddddd;
       text-align: center;
       padding:8px;

   }
</style>
   <h1>Formulary</h1>
<hr/>
<h1>Products</h1>
<table>
   <theading>
       <th>Product ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Ingredients</th>
       <th>Actives</th>
       <th>Form</th>
   </theading>
   {% for product in product %}
   <row>
       <tbody>
           <td>{{product.id}}</td>
           <td>{{product.name}}</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td>{{product.form}}</td>
       </tbody>
   </row>
   <tbody>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
<hr/>
<h1>Products|Ingredients</h1>
<table>
   <thead>
   <row>
       <th>Product Line Item ID</th>
       <th>Active</th>
       <th>strength</th>
       <th>Units</th>
       <th>Product Linked to</th>
       <th>Active Linked to</th>
   </row>
   </thead>
{% for object in productList %} 

<tbody>
   <row>
       <td>{{object.id}}</td>>
       <td>{{object.active}}</td>
       <td>{{object.strength}}</td>
       <td>{{object.UoM}}</td>
       <td>{{object.linked_product}}</td>
       <td>{{object.active}}</td>
   </row>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<hr/>
<h1>Actives</h1>
<table>
   <row>
   <thead>
       <th>Active ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Form</th>
       <th>"Product|Ingredients" linked to</th>
   </thead>
</row>
   
       {% for active in active %}
   <row>
       <tbody>
       <td>{{active.id}}</td>
       <td>{{active.long_descr}}</td>
       <td>{{active.drug_form}}</td>
       <td></td>
       </tbody>
   </row>
   {% endfor %}
   
</table>
```

[Image of information layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEJJo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `product_line.linked_product` to get linked_product info in `views.py`

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems and you could expand it. Try to improve that. [**TIPS**]: Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. To highlight apps' names or interface, use a **bold** (`**` brackets) or *italic* (`*` brackets) font. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using `Enter` everywhere.

Comment: This didn't work.  Could you please expand a little in case I am not understanding your code.

Comment: If you want to get Product for each Product_Line，You can write like this  
`productList = Product_Line.objects.all()  
for pro in productList:  
 product = pro.linked_product`
If you want to show it on the page, you can use double-layer loops.
I haven't written Python for more than a year. Please forgive me if it's wrong

Comment: Please don't add code in comments, it's unreadable. [Edit] your answer instead.

Comment: @Colin Have a preview mode bellow your answer, when you publish check it out first.

Comment: sorry,I've just registered. I'll pay attention next time@NguyễnVũThiên